# Solidity Ide- interface error: Contract "Cat" should be marked as abstract

Tags: interface, solidity, abstract

I'm new with Solidity, and used version 0.8.7 !

I'm practice abstract contract and interface but get this error : **Contract "Cat" should be marked as abstract.**

And here it's my code below.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

abstract contract Animal {
    uint8 head = 1;
    function braking() public virtual pure returns(string memory);
}

interface get {
    function getHeadNumber() external returns(uint8);
}

contract Dog is Animal, get{
    function braking() public override pure returns(string memory) {
        return "Woof!!";
    }

    function getHeadNumber() public override view returns(uint8) {
        return head;
    }
}

contract Cat is Animal, get {        < < < error here !!!!

    function braking() public override pure returns(string memory) {
        return "Meow!!";
    }
    
    function getHeadnumber() public override view returns(uint8) {
        return head;
    }
}
```

I want to know why contract Dog can without abstract, but contract Cat can't !!

If u need [detail error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxQ87.jpg)

Sorry for my bad English, hopes you have a wonderful day.

Many Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to case sensitivity:

The `interface get` defines `getHeadNumber()` (capital `N` in `Number`).

But the `contract Cat` is trying to override `getHeadnumber()` (lowecase `n` in `number`).

**Solution:** Rename the function in `contract Cat` to `getHeadNumber()` (capital `N`).

Comment: Yes I see that ... what a stupid question I asked.. 
Thank you so much, I will pay more attention in the future !!